# No user folders Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: directory, home-directory

As a learning excerise, I have installed Ubuntu (from scratch) using the alternate install CD and then building on top of that. Installing an xserver, a display manager, a window manager etc. I've learned a lot.

I now have Ubuntu 12.04, an xserver and the gnome-core desktop (which includes GDM and a whole host of other core stuff). I've installed a theme and so on and so forth, and it's looking pretty good. Rather pleased with myself lol

But.... I have no home folders. I have the directory /home/myname  but I don't have /home/myname/Documents, /home/myname/Pictures etc. You know the ones, with the emblems on them.

What have I missed out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I worked it out. The process responsible for checking user folders at login, and creating them if they dont exist, is `xdg-user-dirs`. The list of default folders can be edited but I just left them at the default. I installed the package:

```
sudo apt-get install xdg-user-dirs
```

Then I logged out and logged back in again. My user folders where there, in my home dorectory, and using the special icons.